# Starting a second JavaFX Application

Tags: java, javafx-2, javafx

I'm trying to launch a JavaFx application from within a JavaFx application, but it looks like Application.launch() can only be called once. Does this mean I have to start a separate JVM... as in exec("java... or is there another way?

More background info. I want my JavaFx app to be able to build and run JavaFx apps. Right now it compiles classes in-memory, loads the classes... it would be really unfortunate to have to resort to writing everything to the filesystem so I can get a jar on the filesystem, so I can use exec to start it up.

As a secondary question... Is there a way to open another JavaFx window and get the stage and pass it to my newly compiled and loaded Application sub-class?

Comment: I just had a thought... no time to test at the moment. Could I create another class loader, load the java fx classes and mine, then call Application.launch() again?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

If you want to execute another JavaFX application in the same JVM you can just create instance of it, manually create `Stage` and call `Application#start()`

```
public void runAnotherApp(Class<? extends Application> anotherAppClass) throws Exception {
    Application app2 = anotherAppClass.newInstance(); 
    Stage anotherStage = new Stage();
    app2.start(anotherStage);
}
```

N.B.: it wouldn't work if you use special features of standard initialization in anotherApp, e.g. `Application.init()` or `Application.getParameters()`

Comment: Please, see question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30445375/javafx-second-application-throws-not-on-fx-application-thread as it's about your solution.